# Does MQ api support alias modify

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I can use the Java MQ Api to put and get messages.
I can also disable gets and put on a queue.

During a migration project, we'll have an App running in parallell. Old and New. Old and New will have their own separate queues. I regulary have messages from a client going to Old.  Occasionally want the msgs to flow to New instead.

wondering if MQ supports a gate/switch concept. where via API I can point a queue to go only to New, or only to Old, for a short time.

Trying to avoid going to message based routing via WMB since I dont have to do that today.  THe parallel mode is only for a few months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not mention the version of MQ or whether there are message affinities or dependence on preserving the `MQMD.MsgID`.  These are critical in devising a solution to this problem.  I'll try to describe enough options so that at least one will be viable whatever version you are at.

**Pub/Sub**
The easiest thing to do is to have the messages arrive on an alias over a topic.  Any message that arrives is published immediately on that topic.  Then it is a simple matter to generate administrative subscriptions to direct messages to the queues on which the apps needing the messages are listening.  This is entirely a configuration change and requires no external components, processes or code.  It is available from v7.1 of MQ and higher, which is to say any of the currently supported versions of MQ.

The down side is that IBM MQ will change the `MQMD.MsgID` from the time the message is received on the topic to the time it is published on the application's input queue.  This breaks the app's ability to use the `MQMD.MsgID` of the incoming message as a correlation ID when replying.  If the requesting app pre-loads the correlation ID or doesn't rely on a correlation ID, this is not an issue.

**Aliasing**
But for apps where this is an issue, it gets a bit harder.  You can alias over a queue and have inbound messages land on the alias.  When you need to switch from one queue to another, you change the alias.  There are a couple issues with this.  The first is that it is never possible to deliver the message stream to more than one of the applications.  In a parallel processing test it is often desirable to do exactly that and then compare summary or detail reports.

The second problem is more operational in nature.  It isn't possible to change the alias while it is open.  If the messages arrive over a `RCVR`, `RQSTR` or `CLUSRCVR channel, no problem.  Stop the channe, switch the alias and restart the channel.  In a series of MQSC script commands this can be done faster than it can be typed.  However, if the applications putting the messages are connected in bindings mode or via client directly to the alias, they must all be stopped in order to change the alias.

That said, aliasing works on all versions of MQ out of the box.

**Physical copy**
One solution that's been around for quite some time is to use the `Q` program ([SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01)) to direct the messages.  In this scenario, the queue on which messages land is a local queue.  The `Q` program is either triggered or set to constantly listen on the queue.  When a message arrives, `Q` then copies it to one or both of the destination queues.

Switching the behavior if `Q` is triggered involves pre-defining 2 or 3 processes where each defines a different behavior - move new messages to `QUEUEA`, to `QUEUEB` or to both.  Changing the queue's `PROCESS` attribute to point to a different process results in an instantaneous change of the behavior.

Alternatively, if Q is configured to listen on the queue forever then changing the behavior involves use of three different scripts to execute it where one causes messages to be copied to `QUEUEA`, another to `QUEUEB` and another to both queues.  Changing the behavior involves killing the script and starting a different one.

The `Q` program works with all versions of MQ, regardless of whether it is triggered or scripted.

Downsides to this approach include the obvious - more moving parts.  You have to trigger the queue or else make a transactional program act like a daemon.  Not hard but if you are betting the business on it then perhaps some monitoring is in order to make sure the input queue doesn't start building.

**Recommendation**
Of all these methods, I *really* like the Pub/Sub version.  It is extremely reliable, has the least moving parts, and if anything breaks it's under IBM support.  When you need to change something, you can do that with minimal impact to the running applications.  If at all possible, use that.